# Weasyprint: Create pdf in base64 without saving it

Tags: pdf, base64, weasyprint

How can I encode my Weasyprint PDF into a base64 string?

This is my current code to generate a PDF for my Django View to open the PDF in the Browser.

```
template = get_template("payment/invoice/default.html")
context = self.get_context_data()
html = template.render(context)
response = HttpResponse(content_type="application/pdf")
HTML(string=html).write_pdf(response)
```

Comment: It's more helpful to also state the import statements because while it's obvious *to you* where `HTML`, `HttpResponse`, and `get_template` are imported from, it's not that obvious to *everyone*.

Answer (score 5):

Solved it. This is the code

```
template = get_template("payment/invoice/default.html")
context = self.get_context_data()
html = template.render(context)
byte = HTML(string=html).write_pdf()
encoded = base64.b64encode(byte)
encoded = encoded.decode('utf-8')
return encoded
```